# react native webview navigation issue

Tags: react-native

I am making a test with react navigaton and webview , I have 2 screens , Home and Details , at details screen I am calling / opening a webpage inside webview , let's say that I am calling stackoverflow.com (Page A) , my problem is that when user click a link of the stackoverflow page and navigate and after wants to go back to the previous page (Page A) , it doesn't go , its going or navigating to the Home screen !!!
how can I let The user go back to the previous page. ?
that 's how I am calling the page

```
<WebView
        javaScriptEnabled
        source={{uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As we know built in back button is not provided in iOs but it is provided in android .

So for considering both platform there is two possibility.

**Android.**

-> For android you have to define `BackHandler` so here are the step.

1. `import` it like this.

   `import {BackHandler } from 'react-native'`.
2. initialize `backhandler` inside the life cycle methods.

   ```
   componentDidMount() {
       BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
   }

   componentWillUnmount() {
       BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
   }

   handleBackPress = () => {
      if (this.state.canGoBack) {
         this.refWeb.goBack();
       }
     else{
       this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
       }
     return true;
   }
   ```
3. define a userdefine variable `canGoBack` inside the `status`.

   ```
     constructor(props) {
       super(props)

       this.state = {
         canGoBack: false
       }
      }
   ```
4. create a method which detect the change in navigation of the webview and bind it with the web view.

   ```
    onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
         this.setState({
         canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
      });
    }
   ```
5. Bind it like this.

   ```
           <WebView
               ref={(myWeb) => this.refWeb = myWeb}
               onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}               
               source={{ uri: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51712310/react- 
               native-webview-navigation-issue' }} />
   ```
6. And thsts it you are ready to go..

**iOs**

For iOs you didn't have to bother too much.

1. Create a button for back press above the `webview` or according to your design logic
2. Follow the above `webview` and navigation logic . forgot about the `backhandler` and set this code inside the `onPress()` method of your created `button` of `backpress`

   ```
   if (this.state.canGoBack) {
       this.refWeb.goBack();
   }else{
       this.props.navigation.goBack(null)
   }
   ```

Note : Here I use `stackNavigator` for screen navigation so i used `this.props.navigation.goBack(null)`  this code. if you didn't use it then dont consider this code and replace with your feasible navigator code in `else` condition

Thankyou..

Comment: Perfect !! I have found several solutions  but it is best and working perfectly . !!

Comment: I tried, the above, but canGoBack is always returning false. Detailed description : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66333341/react-native-webview-navigation-issue-on-hardware-back