# react native webview navigation issue on hardware back

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am opening a url in webview. On opening the webview (let say page A), when i traverse or go inside any other options by clicking some options, some other page gets opened (let say page B). Now when i click on the hardware back option, i want to return to the previous screens that is (page A). And again n clicking back, i want to return into my app.

Tried following,

```
const [canGoBack, setCanGoBack] = useState(false);
const WebViewRef = useRef<WebView>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", HandleBackPressed);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", HandleBackPressed);
    };
  }
}, []);

<WebView
  ref={WebViewRef}
  // onLoadStart={() => setLoading!(true)}
  onLoadEnd={() => setLoading!(false)}
  source={{ uri: props.navigation.getParam("x") }}
  onNavigationStateChange={(data) => handleResponse(data, WebViewRef)}
/>;

const handleResponse = (data: NavState, WebViewRef: any) => {
  console.log(data.canGoBack); // <- always false, if i can go back further back or not in a webview
  setCanGoBack(data?.canGoBack!);
};

const HandleBackPressed = () => {
  if (WebViewRef.current && canGoBack) {
    WebViewRef.current.goBack();
    return true; // PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR (EXITING THE APP)
  }
  return false;
};
```

How to achieve it?

Comment: what's the problem with your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the `canGoBack` updates are not reflected in the backHandler method since the useEffect only gets run on init.

You can make that effect depend on the canGoBack as follows:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        () => {
          if (webViewRef.current && canGoBack) {
            webViewRef.current.goBack();
            return true; // PREVENT DEFAULT BEHAVIOUR (EXITING THE APP)
          }
          return false;
        }
      );

      return () => backHandler.remove();
    }
  }, [canGoBack]);
```

You can see a working snack example here: https://snack.expo.io/QcYE9CTaO

It would be a bit cleaner if you can wrapped the backHandler method in a `useCallback` so that depends on the state value and then a useEffect that depends on the new `backHandler`.